# Separate layouts for scopes in cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.x

I have application that works in 2 diffrent scopes

```
Router::scope('/', function (RouteBuilder $routes) {
    $routes->connect('/', ['controller' => 'Homepage', 'action' => 'display', 'prefix' => 'Dsp']);
    $routes->fallbacks('DashedRoute');
});

Router::scope('/cms', function (RouteBuilder $routes) {
    $routes->connect('/', ['controller' => 'Dashboard', 'action' => 'display', 'prefix' => 'Cms']);
    $routes->fallbacks('DashedRoute');
});
```

Is that possible to have separate layout (default.ctp) in App/src/Template/Layouts for each scope?

Comment: Why are you mixing scopes and prefixes like that? Wouldn't it be better to do it the other way around (if at all), ie use prefix routing and nest scopes inside? Per prefix layouts also would work out of the box.